# Measuring The Star

Tags: geometry

In a regular pentagon the diagonals are joined to form a star.

The star occupies what percent(%) of the pentagon's area?
[image]

Comment: Look for similar triangles.

Comment: Hint: Subtract the white triangles from the pentagon.

Comment: http://www.contracosta.edu/legacycontent/math/pentagrm.htm

Answer (score 0):

a well-known (and easily demonstrated) fact is that the four main lengths occurring in the diagram are in geometric progression with ratio $\phi$, the golden section.

if the inner pentagon is ascribed unit area, then the outer pentagon has area $\phi^4$

in the area between the two pentagons, the shaded area occupies $\frac1{1+\phi} = \frac1{\phi^2}$ of the total.

hence the required ratio is:
$$
\frac{1+\frac{\phi^4 -1}{\phi^2}}{\phi^4} = \frac2{\phi^3} = 0.472...
$$